# Java type and Native type

Tags: java, types, native

---

I want to call external **dll function** from java code. I'm using Netbeans IDE 7.2.
My dll's functions are:

```
Boolean  isValid(String  word)
List<String> getWords(String  word)
```

I'm following [this](http://blog.mwrobel.eu/how-to-call-dll-methods-from-java/) example. But I don't know how to declare my dll functions.

`List <String>` match in Native type?